# Homescreen unresponsive after disconnecting Xamarin debugger

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I am debugging my app on my iPhone and I disconnect the USB cable without stopping the debugger, my iPhone's homescreen becomes unresponsive.

I can't open any app, I can swipe between pages and open folders, but when I tap on an icon to open an app, it becomes gray and refuses to open.

When my iPhone is locked when I disconnect the cable, I can't even go to the homescreen. It recognizes the TouchID, but refuses to unlock.

I can't even get the "slide to turn off" to appear when I try rebooting. The only solution I have found is to force shutdown by pressing the home button and the lock button at the same time.

It is very annoying to check if the app is currently connected to the debugger to disconnect it first when I need to quickly go somewhere with my phone.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: its a known issue with the Xamarin Studio unfortunately.

Comment: @iamIcarus no workaround that you know of?

Comment: I haven't found (or seen) any workarounds personally. Not sure if this happens with Visual Studio as well as Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @iamIcarus yes it does, I am using it. I'll add it to the question